# How many food trucks entered Gaza during the war compared to before the war?

Tags: israel-hamas-war, transportation, gaza

IPC's current [report](https://www.ipcinfo.org/fileadmin/user_upload/ipcinfo/docs/IPC_Gaza_Strip_Acute_Food_Insecurity_Feb_July2024_Special_Snapshot.pdf) on Gaza says:

> From a pre-escalation average of 500 trucks a day of which 150 carrying food, in the period between 7 October 2023 to 24 February 2024, only 90 trucks per day, of which only 60 carrying food, entered the Gaza Strip.

AIPAC [reports](https://www.aipac.org/resources/israel-humanitarian-aid-gaza) (probably based on COGAT numbers, but I'm not entirely sure of their source) "Updated 3/20/2024":

> During the war, more food trucks have entered Gaza than prior to the war — on average an increase of more than 50% per day.

**IPC reports 60/150 = 0.4 as many food trucks as before the war. AIPAC claims >1.5.** These two statements probably can't be both correct if using the same measure of "food trucks", even accounting for the one extra month that AIPAC claims to account for.

N.B. there's a Web Archive [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20240202022739/https://www.aipac.org/resources/israel-humanitarian-aid-gaza) of that AIPAC page from 1/29/2024, and it contains nearly the same claim in that regard: "Today, more food trucks are entering Gaza than prior to the war — on average an increase of more than 50% per day."

Possibly the baseline differs too. The AIPAC claim resembles a bit [one](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/cogat-says-it-is-working-to-boost-aid-into-gaza-claims-there-is-no-food-shortage-in-strip/) by a COGAT official in early January (but note some differences):

> Col. Moshe Tetro, head of COGAT’s Coordination and Liaison Administration to Gaza at an on-site press briefing. “Before the war there was an average of 70 trucks carrying food entering Gaza every day. The average last week was 110 trucks.”

COGAT claims the pre-war average number of food trucks was 70/day, IPC says it was 150. That's a factor of 2 right there, before even talking about wartime numbers.
(Interestingly enough, that 70 is lower than the 106 figure [published](https://www.reuters.com/article/idUSBRE89G0NM/) in an Israeli government study from 2008 titled "Food Consumption in the Gaza Strip - The Red Lines", as the minimum to "maintain the basic fabric of life" in Gaza, although that apparently included "essential goods" besides food, so it's somewhat inconclusive. But from the Gisha [translation](http://www.gisha.org/UserFiles/File/publications/redlines/red-lines-presentation-eng.pdf) (table on slide 4) the [minimum] number of food trucks was estimated to be 77, in that study. Based on slide 8, that 77 figure was supplemented by an additional 12-truck equivalents supplied via the later demolished Karni conveyor belt. The conclusion on slide 14 says that "about 90 truckloads of basic food, certainly meets nutritional needs in the Gaza Strip". FWTW, the Israeli government says they never made use of that study.)

Comment: This seems like too much of a current event to get answers. I just heard an NPR interview with an Israeli official who said there was no starvation, and also the starvation was Hamas's fault. Then the New York Times has an article yesterday that a video taken Oct. 7th completely disproved a later accusation of sexual assault, but then added there could be some unknown kibbutz where it took place instead. We go off of sources, and if the sources are all over the place, that's political analysis which isn't a Skeptics thing.

Comment: @OwenReynolds: ok, but this Q is not about who steals/takes the food after the trucks enter, or any of the other whattaboutism. It's a basic disagreement on the number of food trucks entering (relative to some pre-war standard). There have been a lot of [non closed] Qs here about this war, especially about Israeli victims.

Comment: There may be other sources we can look at. We would need to be careful to look at independent sources - there will be lots of sources which just parrot someone else's numbers. But if we can find independent sources and they roughly agree with one of the estimates and not the other, then that's helpful. E.g.  UN Office for the Coordination of Humanitarian Affairs tracks truck numbers, is that a separate source?